# Can not get a pdf out

Tags: titles

I'm kinda new in LaTeX environment. I started with downloading MiKTeX and TeXstudio. I installed both and they were installed and runned smooth. My purpose was to write a Springer LNCS in LaTeX format. So I downloaded `.sty` files and etc. from [here](ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/llncs/latex2e/llncs2e.zip) and I put them into same folder as my tex file that I'm working on. I started with these lines:

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym,amsmath}
\begin{document}
content...
\end{document}
```

Compiling these lines gave me a pdf file only written "content" in it. But when I changed it to following;

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\title{eyestates}
\end{document}
```

I was not able to get a PDF output nor a DVI after. What could be the possible problem. Am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx. You can mark code sections by indenting 4 spaces (or just use the `{}` button. simmilarly you can use backticks to make inline code. Please post the exact error message you got from tex (it will be in the `.log` file.)

Comment: You have to use `\maketitle` to print the title. `\title` just stores the value of the title

Comment: This because your document is empty and no pages of output are generated.

Comment: You will need some more content in your document: `\title` does not print anything it just saves the information for `\maketitle`. Is that the only issue, or do you actually get an error in processing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\title` does not print anything (in the `llncs` class nor in the standard `article` class) It just saves its content to be printed by `\maketitle`. You need

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{amssymb,latexsym,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\title{eyestates}
\author{me}
\institute{tex.sx}
\maketitle
\section{hello world}
content
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That was the solution indeed. And sorry for not typing according to forum rules.